# Use of unresolved identifier 'Message' in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, message, identifier

I am trying to get the notification details such as message or image or something when then app is on background and it to the persistentContainer.I am getting `Use of unresolved identifier` when using `Message` method.How can I fix this???

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        let text=userInfo["text"] as! String
        let image=userInfo["image"] as! String
        guard let url=URL(string: image) else
         {
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
         }
        let persistentContainer=NSPersistentContainer(name: "PushMe")
        let context=persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.perform
            {
                do
                {
                    let message=Message(context:context)

                }
                catch{

                }

             }
    }
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is Message? How is it declared?

Comment: that is a built-in method

Comment: Message must be a type, a struct or a class, and not a method. Where do you expect it to be a built-in, swift or UIKit or...?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firebase for push? If so, add this line at the top of the file:

```swift
import Firebase
```

Also consult the docs:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive

Comment: Not using Firebase or any other third party libraries.What I am trying to do is storing user notification details(message,image,date...etc) when app is in background and displaying when the user opens the application.

Comment: In that case, where is the `Message` class coming from? It's not part of iOS. Do you define in your code? Do you use a library that defines it?

Answer (score 0):

- Clean the project `cmd + shift + k`
- Remove Derived Data folder `Xcode preferences > Locations > Derived Data`
- Restart Xcode
- (if error is on simulator) Clean your simulator:
  `Device > Erase All Content and Settings`.
- Remove all the references to your App, like app and test.

This will be because your simulator/Device had some UItest or whatever of another scheme, this created some conflict.